# viewForFooterInSection caught in infinite loop

Tags: uitableview, ios5, crash, ios6, infinite

Why does the following code work fine in iOS 6. But in iOS 5 it gets caught in an infinite loop that causes the device to crash. Once the line "self.footerView = ..." is executed, it calls viewForFooterInSection again. Therefore trapping it in an infinite loop.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!self.footerView)
        self.footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[tableView rectForFooterInSection:section]];

    return self.footerView;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Why does this work on iOS 6 but not 5?

Regards,

Peter

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that `rectForFooterInSection` is calling the delegate method `tableView:viewForFooterInSection:` in order to compute the view frame.

It seems reasonable to me (and expected) that this goes into an infinite loop.

You are basically telling that the `footerView` for section `x` is a `UIView` with the same frame of the `footerView` of section `x`, the very same you are supposed to return. Can you see the recursive issue here?

Apparently there has been some implementation change in iOS 6 that prevents the infinite loop (probably relying on some default value for the footer frame), still the above implementation of the delegate method is definitely wrong.

You should define your `footerView` independently and return it in the delegate method.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. This way of setting the footer works best for me because I want to refresh that footer periodically and it is nice to have a handle to the label. Just return nil if you are recursing, and apple will help you figure out the rectangle (even in iOS 4.3 through 5.1).

```
static BOOL alreadyCheckingFooter = false;
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!self.footerView) {
        if (alreadyCheckingFooter)
            return nil;
        alreadyCheckingFooter = true;
        self.footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[tableView rectForFooterInSection:section]];
        alreadyCheckingFooter = false;
    }

    return self.footerView;
}
```